# How to compare between local and cloud file Azure

Tags: c#, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have a local site where I can add or delete attachments. After I add an attachment they get uploaded to Azure Blob storage. But I do not get direct information except the name of the files currently attached. I am looking for an efficient mechanism to compare files between there local and cloud instances. For example if user adds files A and B, they get uploaded to Azure. Then if user edits A and reuploads I need to compare the contents of the files between local and Azure and if there is a change reupload. Also if the user deletes file B I need to make another check if FIle A is not edited. So far I have thought about comparing the stream content. Are there any other efficient ways to do so?

Comment: Perhaps make use of the Content-MD5 field on Azure blob storage to do quick comparisons between remote and local files?  Compare that hash with an MD5 of your local files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bryan gave the right direction. I would use Event Grid to generate the MD5 version, then would store it into a key value pair store. Then before uploading the new one, just would lookup the key value pair and compare both MD5 versions.

Here are some useful links that uses s3, but could give you some insights:

-[How to compare versions of an Amazon S3 object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40138780/1384539)

-https://github.com/micnews/s3-diff